# Is it possible to trigger a release with another release in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, release, release-management

In VSTS, is it possible to trigger a release upon the completion of another release? I know the release is typically triggered by the completion of a build, but I am wondering if I can trigger one release with another release, for the sake of organizing my processes into multiple releases and linking them together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a capability at present time, although you could write a custom task using the REST API to accomplish the same thing, or check the marketplace to see if someone has already created a task to do the same.

There are a lot of considerations when you start doing things like this, though. What **build** are you releasing in your "sub-releases"? The latest one? That build might not be stable enough to deploy. A hard-coded value? That's going to be a thing that people forget to update.

Typically, my approach in situations like this are to break down the releases into different discretely deployable units that have no dependencies on other units. They can be promoted through the stages as necessary. Then, if you have the occasional need to just do everything all together (for example, provisioning a brand new environment), have a "combo" release that encompasses everything. There isn't even a need for duplication with the recent introduction of [meta-tasks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#metatasks).

Comment: Yes but, you could use variables to push down values to sub releases.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to meta-tasks in the linked page. (2017-11-27).

Comment: Update: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harshillodhi/2016/11/29/vststfs-understanding-task-groups-and-its-various-use-cases-with-setvariable-logging-command/ `A Task Group (formerly called Meta Task)`

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Release Orchestrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dmitryserbin.release-orchestrator) extension from the marketplace which adds a task to execute and track progress of multiple release pipelines in Azure DevOps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include some context and the essential parts of the answer here, then provide the link for reference. Link-only answers become invalid when the linked page changes or goes offline. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some more info.

Comment: What's with the unnecessary purity & ungratefulness? This answer gave me all that I needed and more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the [VSTS Trigger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergiibomko.vsts-trigger#overview) extension from the marketplace to trigger a new build or release from a build or release.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier option would be to [schedule a release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#scheduled-triggers). If you create a schedule for the release of each of your application repositories you can ensure that they will all reach the servers at the same time. 
Another option is to use [stage scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-scheduled-triggers).